# How to convert postgres UTC into another timezone?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, timezone, utc

Is there a way to convert postgres UTC time to the user's timezone or at the very least Eastern Standard Time (I'd be grateful with either answer)?

I thought that there was a way to [change postgres UTC time,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31639288/how-to-change-timezone-for-postgres) but I don't think there is without causing a lot of issues. From what I read it would be better to use code on the frontend that would convert it to the correct time zone?

This barely makes sense to me.

### What's the point?

So that when a user checks off he completed a good habit, the habit disappears, and is suppose to reshow tomorrow at 12am, but the habits end up reshowing **later in the day** because of UTC.

**habit.rb**

```
scope :incomplete, -> {where("completed_at is null OR completed_at < ?", Date.today)} # aka those habits not completed today will be shown

def completed=(boolean)
  self.completed_at = boolean ? Time.current : nil
end

def completed
  completed_at && completed_at >= Time.current.beginning_of_day
end
```

Comment: so if you add this `config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'` in your application.rb and in your console if you do Habit.last.completed_at does it returns UTC time or Eastern time.?

Comment: config.time_zone let you access your time in specfic time zone using `Time.zone.now` or `Time.zone.beginning_of_day`. if you change your scope abit and add `config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'` in your application.rb you will acheive what you want

Comment: I already have that line @Athar in my application.rb: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31639288/how-to-change-timezone-for-postgres

Comment: okay did you try this `Habit.last.completed_at` what does it return. also change your scope like this `scope :incomplete, -> {where("completed_at is null OR completed_at < ?", Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day)}`

Comment: That returns: `Sun, 26 Jul 2015 12:20:13 EDT -04:00` It works in development @Athar. I'll give that scope a try.

Comment: okay what if you try this `Habit.last.completed_at` in heroku console.? what does that return.?

Comment: Gives: Sun, 26 Jul 2015 14:10:46 EDT -04:00

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84320/discussion-between-athar-and-anthonygalli-com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please change your scope to this, it will search time zone specifically.

```
scope :incomplete, -> {where("completed_at is null OR completed_at < ?", Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day)}
```

Comment: Hey this didn't work for me, but the answer in your comments did: `scope :incomplete, -> {where("completed_at is null OR completed_at < ?", Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day)}` Thanks again :]

Answer (score 0):

Place this code snippet into your application.rb

```
  config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
```

and run this so it will be set on heroku `heroku config:add TZ=America/Los_Angeles`.

Generally, you can also use `#in_time_zone`. Always use the time like `Time.zone.now`.

```
Time.utc(2000).in_time_zone('Alaska') # => Fri, 31 Dec 1999 15:00:00 AKST -09:00
DateTime.utc(2000).in_time_zone('Alaska') # => Fri, 31 Dec 1999 15:00:00 AKST -09:00
Date.new(2000).in_time_zone('Alaska')  # => Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 AKST -09:00
```

[date and time zones](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateAndTime/Zones.html#method-i-in_time_zone)

[api docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html)

Comment: Thanks Adam! I already have that in my application.rb & ran that command: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31639288/how-to-change-timezone-for-postgres